# Парсинг содержимого сайта

Tags: php, парсер

Добрый день, уважаемые форумчане! У меня возникла такая проблема. При разработке одно сайта столкнулся с такой проблемой, как невозможностью парстить данные с другого сайта.

Использую такую функцию:

```
$docHTML = file_get_contents($url);
```

И она работает для всех сайтов кроме одного http://www.banki.ru/banks/ratings/

От этого сайта почему-то данные парсера не возвращаются, не знаю даже что с этим делать. Подскажите как преодолеть эту проблему. Версия php 5.4. Может библиотеки для парсера сайта, даже тех которые защищаются от сторонних роботов.

Comment: Только что проверил - все работает. Что именно у вас не получилось?
Опишите подробнее, что делали, что ожидали увидеть и что получили на самом деле.

Comment: @Johny, Ну что есть сайт вместо $url пишу какой-нибудь гугл или сторонний сайт все выводит, а начинаю выводить этот сайт и ничего. Может быть бан по ip-адресу из частого парсинга данных с того сайта? Такое возможно?

Comment: Проверяйте с вашего хоста:

`wget -S http://www.banki.ru/banks/ratings/`

Comment: Посмотрите код ответа. Попробуйте использовать, например, wget, и посмотрите, что пишет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробовал запустить:

```
$url = 'http://www.banki.ru/banks/ratings/';
$docHTML = file_get_contents($url);
echo $docHTML;
```

У меня вернуло содержимое целевой страницы.

Вариант с curl_proxy

```
$url = 'http://www.banki.ru/banks/ratings/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '176.114.202.232:3128');
$html = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $html;
```

Список проксей [тут](http://spys.ru/en/)

Comment: Ну что есть сайт вместо $url пишу какой-нибудь гугл или сторонний сайт все выводит, а начинаю выводить этот сайт и ничего. Может быть бан по ip-адресу из частого парсинга данных с того сайта? Такое возможно?

Comment: Вполне возможно. Используйте curl_proxy если уж так сильно надо. Обновил свой ответ.